# What is difference between NSUInteger myID and int myID?

Tags: iphone, types

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject {
 NSUInteger myID;
}

@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger myID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`NSUInteger`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html) is unsigned integer and `int` is signed integer

Answer (score 6):

NSUInteger is an unsigned integer, and (can be/should be) used in cases where you are not expecting negative values i.e. the index of an array.

NSInteger is typedef for int , and it includes negative values.

Both having different limits

unsigned int is 0 to 4294967295
signed is -268435454 to 268435455 .

Comment: Good answer, some times does little things aren't as obvious as they seam.